# Update bootstrap in an asp.net core web application + Angular project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a sample project using Visual Studio 2017. The project is ASP.NET Core Web Application with Angular (the Angular template comes with the latest VS2017). The project was created and is working great.

I would like to update the bootstrap to the latest - what would be the best way to do that? I have tried copying over, importing in _Layout.cshtml and Index.cshtml but fails...

I am pretty new in this area, so any help would be greatly appreciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Working with an empty solution here, but should be the same.

- In your solution explorer, under Dependencies, there is a "npm" folder.
- Right click on the folder and click "Open package.json"
- Find "bootstrap" under `devDependencies`, and change the version to the one you want.

  - Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> should show you the latest stable version if you just want the latest

If it doesn't automatically update the package for you then:

- Go back to, and open the "npm" folder in the solution explorer.
- Find bootstrap, and right click and select "Update Package"

Let me know if I missed anything.

Comment: that didn't work for me. I have tried to update this thing in so many ways.